# How to squash two commits which are actually before a merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rewrite-history

assume the following history:

```
   X - Y - M - Z   <- feature
 /        /
A - B - C - D      <- master
```

I want to rewrite history to fixup X and Y into a single commit. So i want the history look like this:

```
    X' -   M'- Z'  <- feature
 /        /
A - B - C - D      <- master
```

All of my attempts so far failed. Most of the time there are conflicts during the rebase. Maybe rebase is not the right way to achieve this?

I understand that (without the knowledge that the effective situation just before the merge hasn't really changed) reapplying the merge from master to feature (M) lead to the same conflicts that i solved in the frist place. The command 'rerere' could be an option to solve this, but as far is a know this is only possible if 'rerere' had been activated also in the first place.

But in this case X - Y do have the same changeset as X'. Why is git not clever enough to just reapply M?. If i just squash X and Y in a single commit X', the original resolved changes (which are stored in M) should again be the correct content for M'. How can i tell git to just take the old content of M to build M' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo `git rev-parse Y A` >.git/info/grafts
git filter-branch -- --all
rm .git/info/grafts
```

<sup>[filter-branch docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)</sup>

grafts are repo-local ancestry overrides.  Anything in git that sees ancestry sees the grafted ancestry, in particular things that rewrite commits see it and so bake it into the rewritten commits.

The filters are shell script fragments, if you want to supply a new commit message you can e.g.

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter="
        [ \$commit = `git rev-parse Y` ] && cat <&3 || cat" -- --all 3<<EOD
your new commit message subject

your new commit message body here
...
EOD
```

Comment: This sounds promissing! My repository is quite large, so a filter-branch would last for about 2 hours if it is run for the complete repository. But the grafting needs to be done in a quite recent area of the history. So is it possible to run the filter-branch command only for those commits which are affected (all child commits of a certain point, including branches that branch of in that part of history)?

Comment: Yes. The `--all` is a `git rev-list`  arg, you can specify anything there rev-list will take.  You could say `--all --ancestry-path Y^!` to get Y and everything that can trace ancestry to it, but nothing in Y's history.  Also, if you've got a decent tmpfs to use, use filter-branch's `-d` option.

Comment: The correct command would be "--ancestry-path --all ^Y". The difference between "^Y" and "Y^!" is very important. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265126 for the whole story... Thanks a lot!

Comment: If one of `Y`'s parents has other children `Y^!` will include them all too, but the alternative, `^Y`, won't work at all, as it will exclude `Y` itself, rendering the filter-branch a no-op.

Comment: ^Y - if seen isolated - is a negative refspec and therefore empty. But in combination with "--all" it will form a set of remaining commits. Then if combined with --ancestry-path it will use the bottom commit of the remaining set to filter out any unrelated commits ("other children"). I just verified that ^Y works and is not an no-op when used with filter-branch. Maybe i miss something?

Comment: I suspect so, only thing I know for sure is  `git rev-list --all --ancestry-path ^Y | grep $(git rev-parse Y)`, prints nothing for me, and when `Y` is the only grafted commit, `git filter-branch -- --all --ancestry-path ^Y` leaves all refs unchanged when I do it.

Comment: jthill's last comment is correct. Whether to use ^Y or Y^! is just a question of should Y be included or not. Currently i prefer to use Y^!: the advantage is, that Y itself is included. The disadvantage (some unrelated paths might also be included if a parent of Y has several children) is not that important for the current use case. It doesn't matter if filter-branch is processing some commits more than required - as long as it is still reduced to a much smaller subset of the repository's history.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout feature
git checkout HEAD~2
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Squash last two commits. And then use `git cherry-pick` to rewrite history with `M` and `Z`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this worked without conflicts, it does not properly reflect the merge commit. The cherry-pick of merge commit "M" will create a non-merge commit M'.

Comment: I think you'll have to move the `master` back to C, and after squashing the two commits of `feature`, you'll have to merge it with master. And then do respective cherrypicking of `Z` and `D` on `feature` and `master`

Comment: Yes, but this would force me to resolve conflicts again. I am looking for a solution to rewrite the history of a long feature branch with several merges from master in between. So i am hoping for a clean, straight forward solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question as i found a hack. I hope git can do it better/easier, so i am still asking for better solutions...

The hack is to start the merge again without commit. Then read all the changes from the original merge (M) into the index and finish the merge. The reset is necessary to clean conflicting files from the working dir. After that continue cherry-picking Z ...

```
git checkout -b featureRewritten A
git cherry-pick X
git cherry-pick -n Y
git commit --amend           #this will actually fixup Y into X
git merge -n C               #start the merge without commit
git read-tree M              #throw away the staged merge results by
                             #replacing them with the original solution
git commit                   #finish commit. need to change the automsg?
git reset --hard HEAD        #throw away any left overs
git cherry-pick Z            #continue
```

Quite a hard work for a long history... Better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution (based on the ideas from jthill):

```
git checkout Y
git rebase -i A
#i-rebase: reword X
#i-rebase: fixup Y
git replace Y HEAD
git filter-branch -- --all --ancestry-path Y^!
git replace -d Y
```

First checkout to detached Y (a unnamed branch ending at Y). The interactive rebase incorporates Y into X and rephrases the message of X. The result is a new commit N. HEAD currently points to it. Now Y (which is still part of branch feature) is replace by N (HEAD). Make permanent with filter-branch. Remove the replacement of Y to get ridd of N.