# How can I limit the log to all the descendants of a given commit?

Tags: git, git-log

Given the history

```
      X-Y    <- feature
     /
A-B-C-D-E    <- master
```

I want to get the descendants of a given commit. One solution seems to be:

```
git log --all --ancestry-path <ref>^!
```

However, the behaviour is a bit strange:

- when `<rev>` is `C`, the result is `CDEXY`
- when `<rev>` is `D` or `X`, the result is `DEXY` (weird!)
- when `<rev>` is `E`, the result is `E`

My understanding is that the command does not get all children of `<rev>`; instead, it gets all children of parent-of(ref). Am I right?

This is unintuitive, error prone, and, quite frankly, irritating. How command should I run instead, in order to limit the log to the descendants of a given commit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## How to limit the log to all the descendants of a given revision

As far as I know, there is no built-in Git command to do that. However, you're almost there. Try

```sh
git log --all --ancestry-path ^<rev>
```

instead. That should limit the log to the descendants of `<rev>`; note that, strictly speaking, `<rev>` is not a child of itself, so it doesn't get listed.

For instance, in my toy repo (I replicated yours; see the bottom of my answer),

```sh
git log --all --ancestry-path ^D
```

limits the log to commit `E`, and

```sh
git log --all --ancestry-path ^X
```

limits the log to commit `Y`.

## What's wrong with `git log --all --ancestry-path D^!`?

### TL; DR

> My understanding is that the command does not get all children of `<rev>`; instead, it gets all children of parent-of(ref). Am I right?

Yes; your *bottom commit* is off by one.

### Details

Because, in your example, commits `D` and `X` are symmetric, let's just focus on commit `D` and deconstruct the command

```
git log --all --ancestry-path D^!
```

According to the [relevant Git man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/revisions),

> A suffix `^` followed by an exclamation mark is the same as giving commit `<rev>` and then all its parents prefixed with `^` to exclude them (and their ancestors).

Furthermore, according to the [`git-log` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log),

> `--all`
>
> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/ are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

Therefore, in your case

```
git log --all --ancestry-path D^!
```

is equivalent to

```
git log --ancestry-path D ^C feature master
```

Moreover, because `D` is reachable from `master`, the latter command reduces to

```
git log --ancestry-path ^C feature master
```

This gives a log of all the commits reachable from either `feature` or master, but excluding `C` or any of its ancestors, and you get commits `D`, `E`, `X`, and `Y`.

As you can see, **your bottom commit is off by one**. What you really want to run

```
git log --ancestry-path ^D feature master
```

which is the same as

```
git log --all --ancestry-path ^D
```

## Test

The following commands recreate your toy repo:

```sh
$ mkdir gittest
$ cd gittest/
$ git init

$ printf "A\n" > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "A"

$ printf "B\n" >> README
$ git commit -am "B"

$ printf "C\n" >> README
$ git commit -am "C"

$ git branch feature

$ printf "D\n" >> README
$ git commit -am "D"

$ printf "E\n" >> README
$ git commit -am "E"

$ git checkout feature
$ printf "X\n" >> README
$ git commit -am "X"

$ printf "Y\n" >> README
$ git commit -am "Y"

$ git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
* e234427 (HEAD -> feature) Y
* cf98c6b X
| * b3d493a (master) E
| * e2bb266 D
|/  
* dfe0267 C
* 0be7d42 B
* 674356e A
```

(Note that commits `D` and `X` can be referred to by their SHAs, or more simply, by `master~` and `feature~`, respectively.)

The command you suggested (I've added the `--oneline` flag, to reduce the output) indeed does *not* limit the log to the descendants of the given commit:

```sh
# master~ = D
$ git log --all --ancestry-path --oneline master~^!
e234427 Y
cf98c6b X
b3d493a E
e2bb266 D

# feature~ == X
$ git log --all --ancestry-path --oneline feature~^!
e234427 Y
cf98c6b X
b3d493a E
e2bb266 D
```

but the one I suggest does:

```sh
# master~ == D
$ git log --all --ancestry-path --oneline ^master~
b3d493a E

# feature~ == X
$ git log --all --ancestry-path --oneline ^feature~
e234427 Y
```

Comment: Great explanation. Now all the three cases above are clear. And it is also clear that the command is just not able to get the requested information (except for special situations). So, how to do that? How to get all refs that are somehow based on a certain ref?

Comment: Great! So the main difference is that " ^D != D^! " because " D^! == ^D^ " which is what you meant by "off by one". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Henning More precisely, `D^!` is equivalent to `D ^D`. And you're welcome!

Comment: That raises another a question: I think i need to adapt my last statement. It is only valid in combination with "--all --ancresty-path". Without those options "D^!" is not producing the same result as "^D^". But also "D ^D" does not. So "D^!" and "D ^D" are not equivalent, right? In addition "D ^D" is not valid for use with "--ancestry-path". Error is "--ancestry-path given but there are no bottom commits". This is all so confusing...

Comment: @Henning Sorry, I made a mistake. I meant: *More precisely, `D^!` is equivalent to `D ^D~`*. Try that and see if you get a "no bottom commits" error.

Comment: Confirmed! And i made a mistake,too: During my tests i accidentially switched from "D ^D" to "D D^". Of course then there is no bottom commit...

Comment: While this question is now perfectly answered, the solution won't work for another issue partly answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31222736/2910279 (see comments). it's about making a graft permanent by filter-branch with only processing affected history (descendants). Processing the whole repository just takes too long. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Henning I haven't had a look, but perhaps you should ask a different question about that problem.